# Transfer variables between tables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On my html I have multiple tables, which are for different valuations. The results of those valuations are supposed to be in another table. The text of `valuation_all` in the `tables.taglist` should be transferred into another table. I'm really lost here. Newby with this topic so I'll appreciate every help!

**Table for summary results**

```html
<table id="results" class="summary">
  <th>Test</th>
  <th>result</th>
  <tr>
    <td>E-01</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-02</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Tables of valuation**

```html
<p>
  <table id="results1" class="taglist">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>result</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="valuation">FAIL</td>
      <td rowspan=2 class="valuation_all">FAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="valuation">PASS</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>

<p>
  <table id="results2" class="taglist">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>result</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="valuation">x</td>
      <td class="valuation_all" rowspan=2>OPEN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="valuation">x</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
```

Comment: 'The text of "valuation_all" in the tables.taglist' neither of those items are referenced in the HTML? If you're looking to change where the data is displayed I'd suggest doing it on the server side, not in JS

Comment: maybe it is E-01 -> #results1 and E-02 -> #results2 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot. The FAIL of the first table is supposed to be displayed in the row of E-01.

Comment: So what should the final output look like? That description still isn't very clear.

Comment: I'm just trying to find an "automated" way to get the value from the valuation_all of the taglisted tables into the first table. I mean I could type them manually, but it's a lot of data.
Goal is to get the text of valuation_all into the rows where now is "text".

Comment: please note, `<th>`s must be wrapped in `<tr>` too

Comment: and tables cannot be a child of p and you should really use a colspan or rowspan to make sure you have the correct number of columns in each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your results list tables are ordered the same way you ordered rows in your global results table, you can perform a `forEach` on all `.valuation_all`, and then mirror each text on the global results table:

```js
const resTables = document.querySelectorAll('.valuation_all')
const results = document.querySelectorAll('#results tr > td + td')

resTables.forEach( function(el, i) {
  results[i].textContent = el.textContent
})
```

```html
<table id="results" class="summary">
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th><th>result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>E-01</td><td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>E-02</td><td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<table id="results1" class="taglist">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th><th>result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="valuation">FAIL</td><td rowspan="2" class="valuation_all">FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="valuation">PASS</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="results2" class="taglist">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th><th>result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="valuation">x</td><td class="valuation_all" rowspan="2">OPEN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="valuation">x</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please consider using data attributes for better matching.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes